# Lauch script if any embeded vimeo is playing

Tags: jquery

I have a section with various vimeo embededds, and I want that when any of them is played, a script that pauses an audio is lauched. I can get it to work with the firs of them, but it doesn't work with the others. I have this code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('.iframevid')[0];
    var player = $f(iframe);
    var status = $('.status');
// Play the video as soon as it's ready
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        player.addEvent('play', onPlay);

 function onPlay(data) {
    var aud = document.getElementById("pla");
    aud.pause();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

This is the first video: and the other links are similar, but I name them player2, or player 3, etc.

```
<iframe id="player1" class="iframevid" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/87197682?api=1&player_id=player1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I get it to stop the audio when any of them is played?? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://johndyer.name/html5-video-wrapper-for-youtube-and-vimeo-api-mediaelement-js/) can help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

With the post about adding a class it was possible, just adding document.ready to beging with initializing listeners.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var iframe = $('.iframevid');

iframe.each( function() {
    var player = $f( $(this)[0] );
    // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        status.text('ready');
        player.addEvent('play', onPlay);
    });

});


var status = $('.status');
});
function onPlay(data) {
    var aud = document.getElementById("pla");
    aud.pause();
}
```